What could cause Rails to structure params as flat rather than hierarchical?
I have a strange error in my rails application that is being triggered by someone probably doing something they shouldn't be doing. But I can't figure out what they might be doing and thus how to guard against it.
The current setup is Rails 7.1.3.2, Ruby 3.3.1, though I've seen it for months including being back on Rails 7.0 with Ruby 3.2
Ultimately, I get the following error:
ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: organization
The form is relatively simple
<form action="/o" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="...">
    <label for="organization_a1">A1</label>
    <input required="required" type="text" name="organization[a1]" id="organization_a1">
    <label for="organization_a2">A2</label>
    <input type="text" name="organization[email_domain]" id="organization_a2">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Continue" data-disable-with="Continue">
</form>
...

Nothing fancy going on in the controller either.
def create
  @organization = Organization.create(organization_params)
  redirect_to start_home_index_path
end

def organization_params
  params.require(:organization).permit(:a1, :a2, ...)
end

The first request comes through and redirects just fine, the second fails on the params.require call
And if I look at the logs, I get the following sequence of requests.
INFO -- Started POST "/o" for 47.238.233.78 at 2024-05-14 17:37:48 +0000
Processing by OrganizationsController#create as */*
INFO -- Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "organization"=>{"a1"=>"v1", "a2"=>"v2"}
, "commit"=>"Continue"}
INFO -- <successful redirect>
...
INFO -- Started POST "/o" for 47.238.233.78 at 2024-05-14 17:37:51 +0000
INFO -- Processing by OrganizationsController#create as */*
INFO -- Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "organization[a1]"=>"v1", "organization[a2]"=>"v2", "commit"=>"Continue", "organization"=>{}}
INFO -- Completed 400 Bad Request in 1ms
ERROR -- ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: organization)
...

So I can see the empty organization pointing at {} in the rails log, but if I look at the body of the request in the error, it appears as
..."organization[a1]":"v1","organization[a2]:"v2"..." with no strange empty assignments like "organization":""
You can see in the logs, this appears to be someone (same IP address) submitting the form twice within 3 seconds. The first succeeds and the second fails.
I've tried to recreate this a number of different ways, including changing the authenticity_token hidden field in the form before submitting (oddly enough, rails does not have a problem with this). Also resubmitting the same request multiple times using curl (no problem). If I change the value of the session cookie, that does cause an error with rails, but a different one (Can't verify CSRF token authenticity).
So what could cause rails to act this way? I can certainly handle this error a number of different ways, but I'd like to understand how the user is able to trigger Rails to act this way.

Would help to add the related form and controller being used.

added the important bits from the form and controller. They're both vanilla implementations, but will hopefully add some useful context.

add id="organization" to your form.  My bet is some browsers are doing their best to guess your intent but cannot.

why don't you use form helpers?

Parsing the form data is done pretty early in the stack by Rack::QueryParser and not Rails. This splits out keys containing brackets into hashes. The error here can seem kind of confusing but the key information is "or the value is empty". If you look at that second request the last key in the hash is "organization"=>{} which is actually overwriting the previous keys.

Can you add the raw request data to the question? "organization[a1]":"v1" doesn't look like well formed formdata which should look like organization[a1]=v1&organization[a2]=v2. It looks like JSON.

@dbugger why would the form need an id attribute? This is perfectly valid HTML.

@max it is valid -- but it could be clearer :)

The most likely answer is that the client sent garbage in the request body.
Parsing FormData pairs into arrays and hashes is done by Rack way before the request passes down the middleware stack to Rails.
ActionController::Parameters is simply a hash like object that Rails uses to wrap the hashes, arrays and scalars that Rack parses out of the request body.
If you look at the incoming request parameters in the log we can spot some big issues.
{"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "organization[a1]"=>"v1", "organization[a2]"=>"v2", "commit"=>"Continue", "organization"=>{}}


The keys "organization[a1]" and "organization[a2]" tell us that the brackets were treated literally and it was not parsed into a hash.
"organization"=>{} is an empty parameter since {}.empty? == true.

The request body you have added to the question is very wrong.
FormData uses = to separate between keys and values and & as the delimiter between pairs - "organization[a1]":"v1","organization[a2]:"v2" looks more like a JSON object.
When parsing JSON brackets in object keys have no significance.
The why is a lot harder to figure out. Could it be a malicous actor fishing for parser volunerabilies? Bad javascript that sends an XHR request but doesn't block the original event? Invalid HTML that causes the browser to try to make sense of the soup?
If you want to replacate the issue just send the following JSON payload:
{
  "organization[a1]": "v1",
  "organization[a2]": "v2",
  "organization": {}
}


I have exact same garbage requests from time to time. GPT has advised many things to filter it and no longer generate errors such as verifying if the model param is present if params[:organization].present? && params[:organization].is_a?(Hash) and log a warning and an empty {} in the else branch of the condition. Will see if fix the issue silently. Otherwise I use the strong params as usual: params.require(:organization).permit...

I think I would add some middleware that looks for brackets in the parsed parameters. Especially for requests where the body is parsed as JSON. I can't really think of any legit uses for that.

I don't think the chatGPT suggestion is actually any good (no suprises there). The whole point of using params.require(:organization) is that you want to bail early and give a "400 - Bad Request" response if the request is garbage. Why would you want to silence it?

Yeah you're right. Actually doesn't make much sense to send an empty hash to my model. Also doing something in Rack seems a bit overkill to silence garbage requests. May just check is the params[:organization] is present before creating my record. Although may still return a 422 unprocessable_entity as I am in a turbo Frame and rerender the :new view.. ?

I think that's it - they are sending garbage requests, I just missed the nuance of it being a JSON payload (it otherwise looks right, no strange injections). curling the payload as JSON rather than a query string does in fact cause the same error.

There are a number of different ways to handle this, I typically like to catch things like this upfront with rack-attack rather than in the controller since next week they'll try it in a different place.

That would be my recommendation as well. Since these two requests are firing so close together simple throttling can prevent it.

You can just use simple form helpers, they will send valid params
<%= form_with model: Organization.new, url: organizations_path, method: :post do |form| %>
  <%= form.label :a1, 'A1' %>
  <%= form.text_field :a1 %>
  <%= form.label :a2, 'A2' %>
  <%= form.text_field :a2 %>
  <%= form.submit 'Continue' %>
<% end %>


While the code in the question  is unidiomatic there is nothing there which actually explains why the parameters would be parsed in that way and this would not actually change anything.

this is solution

No, it's not even an attempt at actually answering the question.
